# How do I store a non-identity column value in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

If I have a table with an identity column as the primary key, I would use scope_identity() to retrieve latest identity value inserted during scope. What if the primary key is not an identity column, but an nvarchar(256) with a default value of newid() to generate the value. After performing the insert, is there a function that I can use to retrieve that value and store it in some variable? I'll need to insert this value into other column ID's in other tables.

Here's an [example](http://superpatrick.files.wordpress.com/2007/11/aspnet_membership_schema_updated.png) of what I'm referring to. In the aspnet_Users table the userID is described like above, if I wanted to use the userID as a FK in my own table, would it be ok to use that autogenerated newid() value or is there a better way? If this is the best way how do I store it easily?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `OUTPUT` clause of the `INSERT` is what you are looking for.  See [this MSDN article.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)

basically:

```
DECLARE @newkey TABLE (keys varchar(25));

INSERT INTO actual_table (nonAutoIncId,other1,other2,other3)
OUTPUT INSERTED.nonAutoIncId INTO @newkey
VALUES ('NewId',1,2,3)
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm looking more into output clauses now.